# Regex to find the word 'checkout' between the words 'require' and 'function'

Tags: regex

Im trying to work out the regex for use in IntelliJ IDEA so I can find all files where I'm importing the checkout module.

Sample code:

... require([ 'admin', 'checkout', 'payment' ], function( ...

Quite possibly a simple one for a regex regular...

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Would it matter if the regex also found this: `/* this requires that the checkout finishes for the correct functionality */`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code I can only point to the most obvious solution:

```
require.*?checkout.*?function
```

will match "the word 'checkout' between the words 'require' and 'function'".
Here is an [example](http://regexr.com?31im8). Is that a sort of thing you had in mind?

Comment: ...and Tim as well. We must've been blind :-)

Comment: Thanks - this is awesome! I've gone with this regex: require.*\\(.*checkout.*function.*\\( example: http://regexr.com?31ioj

Comment: Why did you put .*? and not just .*  ?  Thanks

Comment: @NickMiddleweek: because `one.*two.*three` would, if these words come up again in this order, match both occurrences and everything in between together, ie in `"and a one and a two and a three, go!"` it will match `"one and a two and a three"`. This may or may not be an issue in your particular case but I think its a good idea to keep the lazy quantifier (http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) there.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a Capture Expression

You can set the first backreference or capture expression to *checkout* with the following regular expression:

```
echo "require([ 'admin', 'checkout', 'payment' ], function( ..." |
    perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /\badmin\b.*\b(checkout)\b.*\bfunction\b/'
```

In this Perl example, *$1* is set to the value you want. Your regular expression engine may provide other facilities for storing and retrieving capture groups.

Comment: To be honest, I don't get backreferences but the words admin and payment could be something different. I'm sure this would work so thanks for your reply.